# Instagram Post Notification Cache Location

Tags: notifications, storage, cache, instagram

Instagram has a "post notification" feature which notifies users on a specific user's new posts. These notifications show the image preview in expanded notification view in notification panel. 
The problem I come across is when I click the notification, sometimes I see that the image was removed from the user's profile. However, I was still able to see the preview in the notification panel.
Where are these preview images stored in android system? How can I copy them in order to see?